# Merge statement without affecting records where there is no change in data

Tags: oracle, plsql, merge

I have a stored procedure that takes data from several tables and creates a new table with just the columns I want.  I now want to increase performance by only attempting to insert/update rows that have at least one column of new data.  For existing rows that would only receive the exact data it already has, I want to skip the update altogether for that row.

For example if a row contains the data:

```
ID |   date    | population | gdp
15 | 01-JUN-10 | 1,530,000  | $67,000,000,000
```

and the merge statement comes for ID 15 and date 01-JUN-10 with population 1,530,000 and gdp $67,000,000,000 then I don't want to update that row.

Here are some snippets of my code:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE           COUNTRY ( 
  fromDate IN DATE,
  toDate IN DATE,
  filterDown IN INT,
  chunkSize IN INT
  ) AS 

--cursor
cursor cc is
  select c.id, cd.population_total_count, cd.evaluation_date, cf.gdp_total_dollars
  from countries c
  join country_demographics cd on c.id = cd.country_id
  join country_financials cf on cd.country_id = cf.country_id and cf.evaluation_date = cd.evaluation_date
  where cd.evaluation_date > fromDate and cd.evaluation_date < toDate
  order by c.id,cd.evaluation_date;

--table
type cc_table is table of cc%rowtype;
c_table cc_table;

BEGIN

  open cc;
  loop -- cc loop
    fetch cc bulk collect into c_table limit chunkSize; --limit by chunkSize parameter

      forall j in 1..c_table.count
        merge
          into F_AMB_COUNTRY_INFO_16830 tgt
          using (
            select c_table(j).id cid,
                   c_table(j).evaluation_date eval_date,
                   c_table(j).population_total_count pop,
                   c_table(j).gdp_total_dollars gdp
            from dual
          ) src
          on ( cid = tgt.country_id AND eval_date = tgt.evaluation_date )
        when matched then
          update
          set tgt.population_total_count = pop,
              tgt.gdp_total_dollars = gdp
        when not matched then
          insert (
            tgt.country_id,
            tgt.evaluation_date,
            tgt.population_total_count,
            tgt.gdp_total_dollars )
          values (
            cid,
            eval_date,
            pop,
            gdp );

  exit when c_table.count = 0; --quit condition for cc loop
  end loop; --end cc loop
  close cc;


EXCEPTION
when ACCESS_INTO_NULL then -- catch error when table does not exist
  dbms_output.put_line('Error ' || SQLCODE || ': ' || SQLERRM);

END ;
```

I was thinking that in the `on` statement, I could just say something along the lines of:

```
on ( cid = tgt.country_id AND eval_date = tgt.evaluation_date
AND pop != tgt.population_total_count AND gdp != tgt.gdp_total_dollars )
```

but surely there's a cleaner / more efficient way to do it?

Comment: If your goal is to increase performance, my first bias would be to remove the loop entirely and just do a single `MERGE` of all the data.  That may be substantially faster than doing a `MERGE` in a loop.  SQL should always be faster than PL/SQL.  Beyond that, if you want to only update rows where there is a change, your suggestions for modifying the `ON` clause look to be correct assuming that your columns are not nullable.  If they allow `NULL` values, your predicates would need to get a bit more complicated.

Comment: only ID and DATE are not nullable.  the rest are.

Comment: Then you'd presumably need more involved predicates (i.e. you want to update the data if you are going from NULL to a non-NULL value and if you are going from a non-NULL value to NULL).  I would write it as `(src.col1 != dest.col1 or src.col1 is null and dest.col1 is not null or src.col1 is not null and dest.col1 is null)` but there are other ways to construct the predicates using, say, `NVL` to replace NULL values with an impossible but non-NULL value `nvl(src.col1,'Impossible') != nvl(dest.col1,'Impossible')`.

Answer (score 1):

The otherway you could do it is use ora_hash to get a hash of the row.  So your where clause could be something like.

where ora_hash(src.col1 || src.col2 || src.col3 || src.col4) = ora_hash(src.col1 || src.col2 || src.col3 || src.col4)